# Npm error thrown for different version

Tags: node.js, npm

I have installed the React package with npm by placing it in the `package.json` file like this:

```
"react": "~0.13.3"
```

However, when I build the project I get the following error from npm:

```
npm ERR! code EPEERINVALID

npm ERR! peerinvalid The package react does not satisfy its siblings' peerDependencies requirements!
npm ERR! peerinvalid Peer react-modal@0.1.0 wants react@>=0.12.0
```

But I don't see any issue if `react-modal` needs `react@>=0.12.0` and I have `"react": "~0.13.3"` !?

Comment: Could you put you full package.json here?